# HTML5 local storage save .toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

How Can I save the toggled class into HTML 5 local storage?

This is my simple toggle function:

```
 /* Toggle */
    $('.bar-toggle').on('click',function(){
      $('.container').toggleClass('with_toggle');
    });
```

I don't really understand how to use the local storage and all the examples I came across use the .hide and .show and cannot find anything related to toggleClass

I wouldn't want to use the .show and .hide as they are costly for the browser but just take advantage of my toggle class...

fiddle:
[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6nakkk7x/4/)

codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLvNgB

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage?rq=1 -- You can put the functionality within the callback of the `click` method and check the storage on document load

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- use an id for the element, otherwise won't be able to target that element after toggling (removing) it's class

---

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="bar-toggle">toggle and save state</a>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

---

- use !important to override the background-color

---

```
#container {
   background-color: #ededed;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.with_toggle {
   background-color: #aeaeae !important;
}
```

---

- storing the class name/state of toggled

---

```
//retrieve current state
$('#container').toggleClass(window.localStorage.toggled);

/* Toggle */
$('.bar-toggle').on('click',function(){

   if (window.localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle" ) {
      $('#container').toggleClass("with_toggle", true );
      window.localStorage.toggled = "with_toggle";
   } else {
      $('#container').toggleClass("with_toggle", false );
      window.localStorage.toggled = "";
   }

});
```

---

http://jsbin.com/wimojapowo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

---

Comment: Thank you for this! Have been trying a bunch of solutions and only yours worked for me :)

Comment: Glad to hear! Awesome it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

U can use method "[$(element).hasClass( string class )](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)"

**Example:**

```
$('.bar-toggle').on('click',function(){
    if ($('.container').hasClass('.with_toggle')) {
       // mark as false 'cos in the next step u remove class .with_toggle
       localStorage.setItem("container_with_toggle", 0);
    } else {
       // mark as true 'cos in the next step u add class .with_toggle
       localStorage.setItem("container_with_toggle", 1);
    }
    $('.container').toggleClass('with_toggle');
});
```

**When u access to localStorage:**

```
var container_with_toggle = localStorage.getItem('container_with_toggle'); // return string zero or one ("0" or "1")
//So, u can use ternary
container_with_toggle = (container_with_toggle === "1") ? true : false;
```

And, if you set value like boolean `localStorage.setItem("container_with_toggle", true)`, u can use ternary operator or `JSON.parse`.

```
var container_with_toggle = localStorage.getItem('container_with_toggle'); // return string with boolean notation ("false" or "true")
//Ternary
container_with_toggle = (container_with_toggle === "true") ? true : false;
// Or use JSON.parse
container_with_toggle = JSON.parse(container_with_toggle ); // return boolean true or false
```

Remember, in some browser u need use `window.localStorage`.

Bye!

Comment: hi, I tried this but it doesn't look like it saving the .with_toggle on the .container if the user clicked. My goal is to save/remember that class state.