# Save menu state using localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to save menu state using localstorage. i am using below jquery code to toggle my menu

```
    <nav id="sidebar" class="active">

    <ul class="menu">
    <li> <a href="#">Customer</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Sales</a> </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

    <div>
   <button id="sidebarCollapse"> Collapse </button>
    Right Content
    </div>
```

my jquery code

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        $("#sidebarCollapse").on("click", function () {
            $("#sidebar").toggleClass("active");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");


        });
    });
</script>
```

my menu show/hide functionality is working well. but when i hide the menu and reload, menu will show again. how i save menu state using localstorage? can you help me.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37421008/html5-local-storage-save-toggleclass) and applied. Hope it works.

```
   $('#sidebar').toggleClass(window.localStorage.toggled);


   $("#sidebarCollapse").on("click", function () {
       if (window.localStorage.toggled != "with_toggle" ) {
          $("#sidebar").toggleClass("active", true);
          $(this).toggleClass("active", true);
          window.localStorage.toggled = "with_toggle";
       } else {
          $("#sidebar").toggleClass("active", false );
          $(this).toggleClass("active", false );
          window.localStorage.toggled = "";
       }

   });
```

Comment: not working aruna, when i refresh, state did not save,

Comment: @gihankumara Try adding $('#sidebar').toggleClass(window.localStorage.toggled); before. Edited the answer

Comment: with_toggle replaced with active. now working .. thanks

Comment: wonderful to hear bro :) specially being able to help someone from my country.